# How to create this black seperation line in next.js using tailwind

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

Here's a link to the Prada register page, does anyone know how to create the thin black line between the "NEXT" button and the text below?

https://www.prada.com/us/en/login-register.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`<hr />` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr) and style it with border. Here's a [Tailwind Playground with a working example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/T1EtXIbFkA).